# Syntax error in UPDATE statement OleDbException

Tags: c#, sql, oledb, oledbexception, updateexception

I'm writing an application which stores user information. Currently the user is supposed to update their Name, Height, Weight and Birthday.

```
string height = TB_ClientHeight.Text;
    string weight = TB_ClientWeight.Text;
    string name = TB_ClientName.Text;
    string bday = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
    int heightint = Convert.ToInt32(height);
    int weightint = Convert.ToInt32(weight);
```

It's updated by calling the `public static string` username variable from another form and using that as the `WHERE UserName = @username`.

```
usernamestringo = Login.usernameFromLogin;
```

I've followed other SO answers in this context and corrected some issues (like preventing SQL Injection). However I'm still getting a syntax error while updating these fields as claimed by `OleDbException`.

```
using (OleDbConnection myCon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=O:\Repos\Database\Database.accdb;Persist Security Info=False"))
using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    string query = "UPDATE TPersons SET Name=@Name, SET Height=@Height, SET Weight=@Weight, SET Bday=@Bday " + " WHERE FirstName= @username";
    cmd.CommandText = query;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Height", heightint.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Weight", weightint.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bday", bday.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", usernamestringo);

    cmd.Connection = myCon;
    myCon.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Updated!", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
}
```

The `OleDbException` is:

> Index #0 
>   NativeError: -526847407
>       Source: Microsoft Access Database Engine
>       SQLState: 3000
>       Description (message): Syntax error in UPDATE statement.

Could anyone guide me where my syntax is wrong? Thank you!

Comment: I think you just need one `SET`, followed by all the comma separated field name to value assignments.

Comment: have you looked up how to use the `SET` statement.. you could have saved yourself a ton of time by just doing a simple msdn Update Set` statement.. you only need one `SET` statement separating the rest of the values that follow with a `,`

Comment: I just realised about the `SET` statement thing. Additionally, apparently "Name" is a reserved word so I also did `[Name]`.
The code works perfectly now! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UPDATE syntax is

```
 UPDATE <tablename> SET field1=Value1, field2=Value2 WHERE primarykeyname=Value3
```

The SET keyword precedes only the first column to update, and you have another problem with the NAME column. In Access this is a reserved keyword. Use brackets around that column name (or better change it to something not so troublesome)

So:

```
string query = @"UPDATE TPersons SET [Name]=@Name, 
                 Height=@Height, Weight=@Weight, Bday=@Bday 
                 WHERE FirstName= @username";
```

Not strictly related to your current problem, but you should look also at this article [Can we stop using AddWithValue already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)  The DbCommand.AddWithValue is a shortcut with numerous drawbacks. Better avoid it.

Comment: Missed the issue with the `Name` column. +1

Comment: Yes - I realised the `[Name]` issue as I published my question. Thanks so much for all of your help!